# Программное создание и управление ViewController'ами

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uiviewcontroller

Не очень понимаю, как можно программно (без использования сториборда) создавать несколько VC и как можно между ними перемещаться: передавать данные из одного VC в другой, как по кнопке можно вернуться в предыдущий VC и т.д.

Есть ли какой-то подробный гайд или вы можете кратко объяснить основную суть? В интернете есть либо ответы на конкретные задачи или только информация о том, как это делать с сегвеями через сториборды, но я не нашел подробного полного руководства о том, как можно создавать VC и какие функции чаще всего используются для управления VC и передачи данных между ними.

Answer (score 2):

Опишу все на примере с двумя ViewController. Комментариями в коде даю ответ на ваши вопросы.

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        createPresentButton()
    }
    //создаем кнопку, с помощью которой будем переходить на новый VC
    func createPresentButton() {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Present new VC", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(presentButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
        //позиционирование
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0)
            ])
    }

    @objc func presentButtonTapped() {
        let vc = ViewController2()
        //передача данных на новый VC
        vc.textFromFirstVC = "Test text"
        //переход на новый VC
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    //текст с первого VC
    var textFromFirstVC = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .orange
        createCloseButton()
        createTestLabel()
    }
    //создаем кнопку, с помощью которой будем закрывать текущий VC
    func createCloseButton() {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Close current VC", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
        //позиционирование
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0)
            ])
    }
    //label для отоборажения текста с первого VC
    func createTestLabel() {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 300, height: 100))
        label.text = textFromFirstVC
        view.addSubview(label)

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -100)
            ])
    }
    //действие закрытия текущиего VC
    @objc func closeButtonTapped() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Без сториборда инициализацию первого ViewController делаем в AppDelegate:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window!.rootViewController = ViewController1()
        return true
    }

}
```

Получившийся результат:
[image: ViewController1]

[image: ViewController2]

Если остались вопросы - спрашивайте.